# 'Shrinking' the Hilbert Space a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra is represented on

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This is a follow on question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752360/all-operators-on-subspace-are-scalar).

Suppose that there is a subspace $U\subset H$ a Hilbert space such that for all $f\in A\subset B(H)$ a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra, $f$ restricted to $U$ is scalar.

Would we get an isomorphic $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra if we choose a unit vector $e_u\in U$ and collapse $U$ to one-dimensional space spanned by $e_u$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to ask. What exactly is the $C^*$-algebra that we get "if we choose a unit vector $e_u\in U$ and collapse $U$ to one-dimensional space spanned by $e_u$"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In the linked question we have a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra on $U\oplus V$, and we have the algebra of bounded operators given by: $u+v\mapsto \lambda u+T(v)$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ and $T\in B(V)$. Can we take a norm one element of $U$, say $e_u$, and represent $A$ on $\mathbb{C}e_{u}\oplus V$ instead of on $U\oplus V$? It seems like a $T\in B(U\oplus V)$ (full operator algebra except scalar on $U$) that maps, say, $V\ni v\mapsto u_1+2u_2+v$ would be problem... must try and get a counterexample like this later.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is "yes". Rather than give a full answer, I will just explain why the situation you are concerned about in your comment above  (in which $v \mapsto u_1 + 2u_2 + v$) cannot possibly occur. I suspect that you will be able to put the rest of the story together yourself.

Suppose that $S \subset B(H)$ is some collection of operators. We say that a closed subspace $U \subset B(H)$ is $\mathbf{S}$**-invariant** if $Tu \in U$ whenever $T\in S$ and $u \in U$. It is simple to check, using the definition of the adjoint of an operator, that $U$ is $S$-invariant if and only if $U^\bot$ is $S^*$-invariant. Thus, if $S$ is closed under adjoint, then $U$ is $S$-invariant if and only if $U^\bot$ is $S$-invariant. In particular, since a C*-algebra $A$ is closed under adjoint, the orthogonal complement of any $A$-invariant subspace is also an invariant subspace.

In your situation, you have a subspace $U$ on which $A$ acts by scalar multiplications. Such a subspace is obviously $A$-invariant and so, by the above discussion, its orthogonal complement is also preserved by $A$.

Comment: Will read this again Tuesday and maybe give you some more bounty 